# Деление двух агрегатов в оконной функции

Tags: sql, oracle, оконные-функции

Существует таблица с полями:

```
ГРУППА УРОВЕНЬ 1, ГРУППА УРОВЕНЬ 2, ГРУППА УРОВЕНЬ 3, 
ФАКТ_ПОКАЗАТЕЛЬ, ПЛАН_ПОКАЗАТЕЛЬ, ДАТА
```

Нужно посчитать за отрезок времени отношение накопленных фактических показателей к накопленным плановым показателям по группам уровня 3.

Создал запрос:

```
SELECT
    ГРУППА_УРОВЕНЬ_1,
    ГРУППА_УРОВЕНЬ_2,
    ГРУППА_УРОВЕНЬ_3, 
    SUM(ФАКТ_ПОКАЗАТЕЛЬ)/SUM(ПЛАН_ПОКАЗАТЕЛЬ) OVER(
                           PARTITION BY ГРУППА_УРОВЕНЬ_3) KPI_ГРУПП_3

FROM ТАБЛИЦА
WHERE ДАТА BETWEEN X AND Y AND... AND... AND...
```

Получаю ошибку о неприменимости двух агрегатов в оконной функции.

Comment: Не обманывайте, будет другая ошибка. Приведите пожалуйста текст ошибки полностью.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предложение OVER применяется к строго одной оконной функции, а не к выражению из нескольких функций. Таким образом первый SUM() у вас не имеет своего OVER и считается групповой, а не оконной функции и требует указания GROUP BY.
Должно быть так:

```
SELECT
    ГРУППА_УРОВЕНЬ_1,
    ГРУППА_УРОВЕНЬ_2,
    ГРУППА_УРОВЕНЬ_3, 
    SUM(ФАКТ_ПОКАЗАТЕЛЬ) OVER(PARTITION BY ГРУППА_УРОВЕНЬ_3) /
    SUM(ПЛАН_ПОКАЗАТЕЛЬ) OVER(PARTITION BY ГРУППА_УРОВЕНЬ_3) KPI_ГРУПП_3
FROM ТАБЛИЦА
WHERE ДАТА BETWEEN X AND Y AND... AND... AND...
```